# Make a responsive layout using flex and css grid

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to do a responsive layout, I'm not good with css so I need help.

Here is the code:

```css
.container {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 490px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.columns {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.map {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 150px;
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  min-height: 150px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.content {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightgray;
  max-width: 320px;
}

.cards {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.card {
  background-color: pink;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.card.left {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.texts {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.text {
  background-color: gold;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.text.left {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="map"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="cards">
        <div class="card left">card #1</div>
        <div class="card">card #2</div>
        <div class="card left">card #3</div>
        <div class="card">card #4</div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="texts">
        <div class="text left">text #1</div>
        <div class="text">text #2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically there are two rows.
The first one contains an element with fixed width and height, and on the right four cards.
The second rows contains only two elements.
Each element of this layout has width 150px.

The code shown above works partially.
The first row is ok, the second one no because the gold elements should stay aligned with the cards so when cards are on the right of el1, contents should below the cards.
It is like if there were to be a hidden element (on the left side of contents) that has the same size as el1.

Also I would like everything to always be centered because now it is only if the window width is > 490px.

This is what I'd like to have:

[image]
[image]
[image]

How can I do that?